# SPA apps, and server synchronisation, best practices

Tags: rest, angularjs, single-page-application, synchronization

I am developing a SPA application in Angularjs to load data into my database.

I have a Django back end with tastypie providing a REST interface.

I am trying to populate a flowcell object, which is made up of 8 lane elements. Each lane may contains multiple libraries (say 5 or 6 on average).

```
Flowcell

     Lane 1
         library 1
         library 2
         library 3
     Lane 2
         library 5
     Lane 3 
         library 6
         library 7
         etc.....
```

So at the moment when I add a new library to a lane object, I POST the details to the server then refresh the lane's library list with a GET request, and the display refreshes.

This ensures that the server data and the display data are synchronised. However, it does add a delay while each Lane contacts the server and refreshes itself.

So is it considered better to add a number of libraries to each lane in the client side, then update them together - this will give a smoother user experience, but the display may not reflect exactly what is in the database? (I can imagine this may cause errors if the two get too far out of synch).

Or is it considered better to do what I am currently doing - update multiple small changes, sending more requests to the server, but ensuring the data between the client and the server are consistent?

Comment: Is there more than one person editing the lanes data at the same time?  In other words, can the server data get out of sync even if the user does not mutate it on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Taking the approach of being more granular in your updates will be better.

Primarily, it will create the feeling of less delay for the client. If the changes are small and are fired off when an element is changed, unless the network is really slow, each change should be fast and almost undetectable by the client.

The only thing I would say is that you might not need to do another GET after your POST of changed data. Unless this is some type of shared data model across many users and sessions, if the client makes an update and the POST goes through, the client holds the correct set of data so the additional GET isn't necessary.